# ERROR: 2 matches found based on name: network <nameofservice>_default is ambiguous

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I was building `docker` image using the command

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
```

But it returns me an error

`ERROR: 2 matches found based on name: network officeconverter_default is ambiguous`

This is a bit clear that in my machine there are two networks with the same name trying to exists.

*Question is how to remove the networks from docker networks*

```
PS E:\repos\Github\officeconverter> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                        DRIVER              SCOPE
868c88a83bd6        bridge                      bridge              local
92f7d20ed432        officeconverter_default     bridge              local
3f96cfb7b591        officeconverter_default     bridge              local
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I created the problem by running the same `docker-compose -f <DOCKER-COMPOSE-FILE> up -d` command simultaneously. As an aside this was because a jest test suite attempted to execute two integration tests in parallel, where a setup step of the integration test was to perform a docker compose.

I was able to solve the issue by running `docker network prune` but be wary this may remove more networks than you wanted. This was ok for me because I was on a dev laptop with nothing important WRT docker config. Hope this helps

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The solution is simple!

just remove the networks.

like  `docker network rm <network Id> <space> <network Id> ....`

```
PS E:\repos\Github\officeconverter> docker network rm 92f7d20ed432 3f96cfb7b591
92f7d20ed432
3f96cfb7b591
PS E:\repos\Github\officeconverter> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                        DRIVER              SCOPE
868c88a83bd6        bridge                      bridge              local
```

Comment: You could also run `docker remove prune` to remove all unused networks.

Comment: Sorry but I realised a typo here. I actually meant `docker container prune`!

Comment: When network is ambiguous, this method won't work.

Comment: I have found same issue ``docker network rm <network_id>`` helped me, Thank you.

Answer (score 59):

try:
`docker network prune`

This will remove all your networks.

Answer (score 6):

A solution that worked for me is:

`docker system prune -af`
To remove all unused Docker images, containers, and networks without asking for confirmation.

`docker volume prune --force`
To remove all unused Docker volumes.

Comment: Deleting everything might not be the best idea if you have a complex docker-compose configuration. You may end up losing important information or having to reconfigure your entire set up

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create a new network, with a different network name, and to connect your docker container to it.
There is a similar error that can happen with ambiguous bridge network names.
One guy has made a complete blog post about how to fix this.
I found it very useful as far as I am concerned, and I believe this will be useful to others in similar situation even if you deal with a network that is not bridge: https://www.jorgeanaya.dev/en/bin/docker-network-name-is-ambiguous/

Here is the short workaround from the blog post (all credit goes to Jorge Anaya):

1. Create a new network. Use the parameter -d to specify the driver

   `docker network create -d bridge [new-network-name]`
2. Disconnect the container(s) from the ambiguous network

   `docker network disconnect bridge [container-name]`
3. Connect the container(s) to the new network

   `docker network connect [new-network-name] [container-name]`
4. Optional. Purge our network and get rid off of the unused networks

   `docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)`

And that's all, now we should be able to start our containers.
Don't forget to add `sudo` at the beginning of each command for permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Open cronjob with `sudo cronjob -e`, then, add new line

`*/1 * * * * docker network prune -f`

This will clean non-used networks (if any) every minute.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can `docker network rm <network id>` to *actually* delete them.

But if you need to choose *which one* to delete, you can:

```
$ docker network inspect d5867f0be024
[
    {
        "Name": "minikube",
        "Id": "d5867f0be024b1c81237fba1eaef3f1ff53b75e15ab84d46a13dcde53809934e",
        "Created": "2022-02-16T19:24:57.7203334-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        ...
    }
]
```

... and then see the `Created` time (or other metadata) to make your decision about which to delete.

In my case I needed to delete the newer one and retain the older one.

Answer (score -1):

Just run docker remove prune it will remove all networks and create again.